Git Hub Action - WP Engine site deploy issue
I'm using this documentation: https://github.com/wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy
And my yml file looks like this:
name: Deploy to WP Engine
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine
        uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
        with:
          WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
          WPE_ENV: sixthavenuedev
          REMOTE_PATH: "wp-content/"
          FLAGS: '-r --inplace --exclude=.git'

My Issue - when I push from local to GitHub - if I've deleted a file or folder locally, it is removed from GitHub but during the build to WP Engine, the file/folder isn't removed from the server. I feel it is something with the FLAGS but I can't figure it out.
I was expecting for any deletions on local would be reflected on the server when pushed.

I encountered the same issue and found the necessary flag to add (see https://github.com/wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy/discussions/52). The --delete flag will remove files on the WP Engine server that are removed from the repo.
In your configuration file you can change:
FLAGS: '-r --inplace --exclude=.git'

To this, with the delete flag added:
FLAGS: -r --inplace --delete --exclude=".git"

